# A good extension to JSF that adheres to JSF2.0?

Tags: jsf

I have been looking for a JSF extension (Richfaces, IceFaces, and more) but all seem to be according to JSF1.x and ones for JSF2.0 are still alpha or in development and most of the documentation assumes you're using JSF1.2.

Is there any production well known extension available?

Answer (score 2):

[RichFaces 3.3.3](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces) is compatible with JSF 2.0. It has however no *full* JSF 2.0 integration yet.

[PrimeFaces 2.0](http://www.primefaces.org/) is already JSF 2.0 ready for months, it was the first to do so.

Comment: OK, I went with PrimeFaces. It seems smooth so far. Thanks for the opinions.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion would be biased if I say PrimeFaces I guess :) So for real life experiences please see: http://www.primefaces.org/whyprimefaces.html